# COUNT function in Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table in MS ACCESS 2016 which have two columns. 1st column represents two companies (assume A and B)and second column represents age of employees I need to count and display how many employees in each campany are less than 25 years. How can I accompolish that.Pics are attached.

[image: Table access 2016+Output]

Comment: Please, we want well formatted text, not images!

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use count() to count. Verify age in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an SQL query:

```
SELECT [Company],COUNT(*)
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Age Of Employee] < 25
GROUP BY [Company]
```

Where `Table` is the name of the table and `Company` and `Age of Employee` are the name of the columns (if the columns have a different name, you will have to alter the query a bit).

Comment: Does Access support back-ticks for delimited identifiers?